# Extract selected file from archive fast

Tags: hash, zip, extract, archive, tar

As project growing, old data should be archived to save disk space, but xxx.tar.gz seems very slow for extract selected file for later using. 
Is there a archive format and software can produce a zipped file for fast browse and unzip certain files?

Thanks.

this question is related to https://superuser.com/questions/484075/archive-software-for-big-files-and-fast-index

the answer is http://dar.linux.free.fr/
I am now trying that

Comment: I currently using that command, but it seems very slow, I want to find out a file format like mpq http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tarred and gzipped files, (*.tar.gz), the command

```
tar xzf archivefile.tar.gz list-of-files-to-extract
```

should do it.

You have to ensure that the list-of-files-to-extract has exact path name as specified in the archive file.

Comment: Do you have faster methods to get list-of-files-to-extract? this methods is slow for big files (XX or XXX Gb)